# How to create service user for application and run it at startup from that user

Tags: 14.04, users, upstart, autostart, su

I have an application, that I should run at startup.

I created system user for that application with `useradd -r serviceUser` and made him the owner of application directory.

Then I write startup script and add it to autostart with`update-rc myserver.sh defaults`

My script at `/etc/init.d/myserver.sh`

```
#!/bin/sh

start() {
  cd "/my_server_dir/"
  su -c "./myServer" serviceUser
}

if [ "x$1" = "xstart" ]
then
    start
    exit 0
fi
```

When I run it from my real login user
`/etc/init.d/myserver.sh start`, promt ask me password. But I didn't set any passwords.

I think somewhere I was wrong.

Comment: It's `su [options] [username]`, so `su -c "./myServer" serviceUser`.

Comment: I fix it, same behaviour.

Comment: `useradd -r serviceUser` doesn't seem to add the user `serviceUser`, but just create the group. Maybe give `useradd serviceUser` a try?

Comment: No, user was created. Seem like my problem related to https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/56765/creating-an-user-without-a-password. I will investigate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what you expect, calling `su` will always prompt for a password unless you run it as root which just does everything without prompting or with sudo which will prompt your user password instead.

So if you want to use that serviceUser with su -c and without requiring sudo rights, run `sudo passwd serviceUser` and set a password.

Comment: Thanks, I made it, autostart worked. I could not understand - if I need input user password, how the system would launch it at startup without. But system run's it as root. I think I understand :)